# Can I place all this functionality into an enum?

Tags: java, enums

Can I squeeze this functionality into the enum? I would also like to use the enum in a switch statement in another file. I would also like to make things private if possible. I know you can do a lot more to enums in java but the literature is a little confusing.

```
public static class SCENE {
    public enum scene {
        MENU,
        PLAY
    }

    public static scene current = scene.MENU;

    public static void switchToMenu() {
        current = scene.MENU;
    }

    public static void switchToPlay() {
        current = scene.PLAY;
    }

};
```

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? *No!* [Just because you can, doesn't mean you should](https://www.acxiom.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HH-Just-Cause-1.jpg), and you should not make a enum stateful. --- If you insist, just move the field and methods to the enum. *(highly discouraged)*

Comment: You should make the field `private`. Making anything else private wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Enum Classes (`enum`) are like a normal Classes, but restricted:

- the only instances are the declared constants; no new instance can be created at run time, not even using reflection or `clone`;
- direct superclass is `Enum<E>`;
- cannot be extended;
- cannot be declared `abstract`
- some restrictions involving modifiers.

Despite of that (and some points I forgot), everything that can be done with a *normal* class, can be done with an `enum`: use all kind of fields and methods. Even each Enum Constant can have its own fields or methods.

BUT, as already commented, not everything is meaningful or recommended - like having a state, non-`final` fields.

```
public class Scene {

    public enum Type {   // maybe SceneType?
        MENU,
        PLAY;

        private void switchTo() {  // instance method, just an example
            current = this;  // bad example, should not change `Scene`'s state
        }
    }

    public static Type current = Type.MENU;

    public static void switchTo(Type type) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type);
        current = type;
        /* alternative, to show switch usage
        switch (type) {
            case PLAY: 
                current = Type.PLAY; 
                break;
            case MENU:
                ...
        */
    }

    // just for demonstration, not the best solution
    public static void switchToMenu() {
        Type.MENU.switchTo();
    }

    public static void switchToPlay() {
        Type.PLAY.switchTo();
    }

}
```

<sub>not tested, no IDE was harmed (used), minor errors left for the user to solve</sub>

<sup>I do recommend, for above simple case, to only use the `switchTo(Type)` method in `Scene`; **not** the `switchTo()` in `Type` - added just as an example of what can be done. The `Type.switchTo()` method is *strange*, it is accessing a field of `Scene`, that is being more than just a type, wrong place for such functionality.</sup>

Obs: since Enum Classes work like normal classes, they can also be declared in an own file. But for the posted code, since *bound* to `Scene`, it can stay as a nested enum - must be accessed like `Scene.Type.PLAY` from other classes. (Your SCENE looks like being nested itself - `static` keyword not allowed on top level class - so the real path would be even longer, like`SomeClass.Scene.Type.PLAY`)

Links:

- Java Tutorials, Oracle: [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
- Java Language Specification, Oracle: [Enum Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this using `current` as string

```
public enum Scene {
    MENU  ("MENU"),
    PLAY  ("PLAY");
    private final String current;
    private Scene (String current) {
        this.current = current;
    }
}
```